# Expo React Native PDF download invalid format

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using expo file system to download a pdf. It was successfully downloaded however when trying to open a pdf file it says "Cannot display a pdf of invalid format. First I downloaded pdf from backend and then converted to base64 using buffer.
Here's the reference I followed from **stackoverflow** [Expo React Native, saving PDF files to Downloads folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101413/expo-react-native-saving-pdf-files-to-downloads-folder)

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { StorageAccessFramework } from 'expo-file-system';
import {Buffer} from "buffer";

const downloadFile = async (payment) => {
    const pdf = await grabPdf();

    const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
    if (!permissions.granted) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, 'inv'+payment.invoice_number, 'application/pdf')
            .then(async(uri) => {
                await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, pdf, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
                Alert.alert('Success', 'Successfully downloaded')
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.response.data);
                alert(e)
            });
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
        alert(e)
    }
}
```

Download pdf from backend and convert to base 64 using buffer.

```
const grabPdf = async () => {
    axiosConfig.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
    const response = await axiosConfig('/user/invoice/C0F19758-0001/247')
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error.response.data)
            alert('Error: '+ error.response.data)
        });

    const buff = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64')
    return buff.toString('base64')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by converting pdf to base64 from php backend

`$base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));`

```
return $base64;
```

before passing to react-native